# Routing Error uninitialized constant - how to edit scaffolding routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've used scaffolding to create an app where users can create letters (newbie).

When adding an additional view ('app/views/letters/review.html.erb') for reviewing letter creation I'm running into routing problems trying to redirect

```
redirect_to review_path, notice: 'Letter was successfully created.'
```

via the path I think now should work:

```
match '/review',    to: 'letter#review',      via: 'get'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Full set up, controller:

```
class LettersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_letter, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :review]

  def review
  end

...

  def create
    @letter = Letter.new(letter_params)
    @letter.user_id = current_user.id if current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @letter.save
        format.html { redirect_to review_path, notice: 'Letter was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: dashboard_path }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @letter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Routes:

```
Appname::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :letters
  resources :charges

  devise_for :users

  get 'letter/new'
  root  'static_pages#home'
  match '/review',    to: 'letter#review',      via: 'get'
  match '/dashboard', to: 'account#dashboard',  via: 'get'
  match '/order',     to: 'account#order',      via: 'get'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the route as below:

```
match '/review',    to: 'letters#review',      via: 'get'
```

Your controller name is `LettersController`, notice plural `letters`. So, while defining route you need to specify plural `letters`.

You are getting `uninitialized constant error` because while specifying controller in the review route you used `letter`(singular) so Rails router started looking for a `LetterController` which does not exist. Hence, you get the error.